# Drawing a Zero Pole plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I'm trying to draw  a zero-pole plot for use with some filter design. Since i couldn't find any standard way to go about this, I tried using the polar library of PGFPlots. I'm having some trouble, however. The first plot i did turned out decently, with only poles in it. When i try to add some zeros though, its missing part of the marker used to denote the position.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[enlargelimits=false, % axis x line = bottom, axis y line=right,
% height=5cm, width=5cm, 
ytick={1}, %axis y line*=none, 
yticklabels={},
xtick={0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360},
%xticklabels={},
%separate axis lines=true,
every outer x axis line/.append style={color=red, opacity=0, fill opacity=0},
every outer y axis line/.append style={color=red, opacity=0, fill opacity=0},
xticklabels={0,
$\frac{2\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{4\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{6\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{8\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{10\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{12\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{14\pi}{8}$}
]
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{(0,0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{(2*pi/8,0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{(4*pi/8,0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{(6*pi/8,0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{(8*pi/8,0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{(10*pi/8,0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{(12*pi/8,0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{(14*pi/8,0.9564)};

    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{(0,2-0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{(2*pi/8,2-0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{(4*pi/8,2-0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{(6*pi/8,2-0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{(8*pi/8,2-0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{(10*pi/8,2-0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{(12*pi/8,2-0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{(14*pi/8,2-0.9564)};
    \addplot+[data cs=polarrad,mark options={fill opacity=00, opacity=00, mark=*}] coordinates{(0,1)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

After some testing it seems i get at problem whenever i go above 5 markers. Anything above that, and some of them don't get rendered properly.

Edit: It was a problem with linestyling. I didn't explicitly set it to solid, so it changed after a while. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the partially drawn markers occurs because you used `\addplot +`, with the `+` indicating that the normal plot style list is still going to be used. In the default style list, plots number 6 to 10 are drawn using the option `dashed, every mark/.append style=solid`, so the lines are dashed, but the markers are drawn solidly. Since you use the option `mark options={...}`, you're resetting the `every mark` style, so `dashed` now also applies to the markers (which you clearly don't want).

So either you could add the option `solid` to your `mark options`, or you could solve the whole thing much more elegantly using only two `addplot` commands:

```
\addplot [
        data cs=polarrad,
        mark=o,
        only marks,
        samples=8,
        domain=0:14*pi/8
    ] {0.9564};
```

will plot eight hollow circles at equally spaced positions between the angles `0` and `14*pi/8`. Since I didn't use `\addplot +`, the line style will be set to `black, solid` automatically (this is the TikZ default). A similar plot command can be used for drawing the asterisks.

Also note that you don't have to provide the whole `xtick` list explicitly. You can just say `xtick={0,45,...,315}`: The first two entries determine the starting point and the increment of the list, and the last entry determines the end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[enlargelimits=false,
ytick={1},
yticklabels={},
xtick={0,45,...,360},
every outer x axis line/.append style={transparent},
every outer y axis line/.append style={transparent},
xticklabels={0,
$\frac{2\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{4\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{6\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{8\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{10\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{12\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{14\pi}{8}$},
]
    \addplot [
        data cs=polarrad,
        mark=o,
        only marks,
        samples=8,
        domain=0:14*pi/8
    ] {0.9564};

    \addplot [
        data cs=polarrad,
        mark=asterisk,
        only marks,
        samples=8,
        domain=0:14*pi/8
    ] {2-0.9564};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `only marks` option to put all coordinates in one `\addplot` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[enlargelimits=false, % axis x line = bottom, axis y line=right,
% height=5cm, width=5cm, 
ytick={1}, %axis y line*=none, 
yticklabels={},
xtick={0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360},
%xticklabels={},
%separate axis lines=true,
every outer x axis line/.append style={color=red, opacity=0, fill opacity=0},
every outer y axis line/.append style={color=red, opacity=0, fill opacity=0},
xticklabels={0,
$\frac{2\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{4\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{6\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{8\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{10\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{12\pi}{8}$,
$\frac{14\pi}{8}$}
]
\addplot+[data cs=polarrad,only marks, mark options={color=black, mark=o}] coordinates{
(0,0.9564) 
(2*pi/8,0.9564) 
(4*pi/8,0.9564) 
(6*pi/8,0.9564)
(8*pi/8,0.9564)
(10*pi/8,0.9564)
(12*pi/8,0.9564) 
(14*pi/8,0.9564)};

\addplot+[data cs=polarrad,only marks, mark options={color=black, mark=asterisk}] coordinates{
(0,2-0.9564) 
(2*pi/8,2-0.9564) 
(4*pi/8,2-0.9564) 
(6*pi/8,2-0.9564) 
(8*pi/8,2-0.9564)
(10*pi/8,2-0.9564) 
(12*pi/8,2-0.9564) 
(14*pi/8,2-0.9564) 
(0,1)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want when you write

> Since i couldn't find any standard way to go about this,

Here a code that is standard for me. Some remarks, I forgot how to use `mark=*`in such case and there is a possibility to write `0` instead of `$\frac{0\pi}{8}$` with a macro from print numbers.

**Update** to plot a mark the code is `\draw plot[black, scale=2,mark=asterisk] coordinates {(0,0)};` with the library `plotmarks`!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  arrows,
  calc
}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[gray] circle (4cm);
\foreach \x in {0,2,...,14} {%
\draw[gray,
     decoration={
     markings,
     mark= at position 0.82 with {\draw[black] circle (3pt);},
     mark= at position 0.95 with {\draw[black] (-3pt ,-3pt) -- ( 3pt,3pt)
                                         (3pt ,-3pt) -- (-3pt,3pt)
                                         (0   ,-3pt) -- (   0,3pt)
                                         (-3pt, 0)   -- ( 3pt,  0);}},
    postaction={decorate}
    ] (0,0) -- node[pos=1.1,text=black] {$\frac{\x\pi}{8}$}  (360/16*\x:4.5cm) ;
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that using pgfplots for as little is to use a hammer to swat a fly

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,minimum size=8cm,draw,thin](cercle) at (0,0){};
\foreach \tt in{ 2,4,6,8,10,12,14}{
\draw[thin] (0,0) -- (cercle.{\tt*22.5}) node[pos=1.1]{$\frac{\tt\cdot \pi}{8}$};
}
\draw[thin] (0,0) -- (cercle.{0}) node[pos=1.1]{$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]